# Convergence of integral: $\displaystyle\mathcal I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin^3(1/x)\cos(1/x)}{x^{3/2}+x^2\ln(1+1/x)}dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

This is a question I recently got on an exam:

> Find whether $\displaystyle \mathcal I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin^3(1/x)\cos(1/x)}{x^{3/2}+x^2\ln(1+1/x)}dx$ converges or diverges.

So I substituted $u=1/x$ to get $$\mathcal I=\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin^3 u\cos u}{\sqrt u+\ln(1+u)}du.$$
Now, take $f(x)=\sin^3x\cos x$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x+\ln(1+x)}$ so that $\bigg|\displaystyle\int_1^b  f(x)dx\bigg|$ exists and is uniformly bounded by $2$ $\forall b>1$, and $g(x)$ is non-negative monotone and bounded on $[1,\infty)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=0$.

Thus, by Dirichlet's test for improper integrals, $\mathcal I$ should converge.

**However**, when I plugged the integral into Wolfram Alpha, it repeatedly exceeded its standard computation time. Also, when I input it into [integral-calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/), it wasn't able to calculate it, and when I selected "integrate numerically only", it showed that "cannot compute because integral may be divergent". However, desmos shows that it is $0$. Thus I am confused. If $\mathcal I$ converges, then shouldn't the softwares be easily able to compute its value?

So is there any other method (comparison test, limit ratio test, $\mu$-test etc.) to confirm the convergence/divergence if this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of convergence is correct. Note that the Dirichlet's test gives you also upper and lower bounds: by integrating by parts we have that
$$I=\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin^3 (u)\cos (u)}{\sqrt u+\ln(1+u)}du=-\frac{\sin^4(1)}{4(1+\ln(2))}+
\frac{1}{4}\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin^4(u)\Big(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}+\frac{1}{1+u}\Big)}{(\sqrt u+\ln(1+u))^2}du.$$
Therefore
$$-\frac{\sin^4(1)}{4(1+\ln(2))}<I<-\frac{\sin^4(1)}{4(1+\ln(2))}+\frac{1}{4}\int_1^\infty\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}+\frac{1}{1+u}}{(\sqrt u+\ln(1+u))^2}du=\frac{1-\sin^4(1)}{4(1+\ln(2))}$$
that is $I\in (-0.0740289,0.07362502)$.

A graph of the integral function $x\to \int_1^\infty\frac{\sin^3 (u)\cos (u)}{\sqrt u+\ln(1+u)}du$,  via [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/28ur3bjste), shows a slow oscillating curve.

For a more precise numerical approximation, compute
$$I_R=-\frac{\sin^4(1)}{4(1+\ln(2))}+\frac{1}{4}\int_1^R\frac{\sin^4(u)\Big(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}+\frac{1}{1+u}\Big)}{(\sqrt u+\ln(1+u))^2}du$$
with $R=N\pi$ with $N$ positive integer, then the error can be estimated as
$$0<I-I_R=\frac{1}{4}\int_{R}^{\infty}\sin^4(u)f(u)du=
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^4(k\pi +u)f(k\pi +u)du\\
\leq \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}f(k\pi)\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^4(u) du
=\frac{3\pi}{32}\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}f(k\pi)
$$
where $f(u)=\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}+\frac{1}{1+u}}{(\sqrt u+\ln(1+u))^2}$ is decreasing and positive.

Using Maple, for $R=10000\pi$, I got that $I_R\approx -0.001744631$ with $I-I_R<0.000499744$, that is $I\in(-0.001744631,-0.001244887)$.

Comment: Uh, so is there any explanation to he repeated failures of powerful computation software  in finding the approximate value of this integral? Or, could you please link me to an approximate value as calculated by a software?

Comment: @insipidintegrator  I revised my answer. Using wolframalpha with different value of $R$ you can obtain more evaluations.